# Can't find cause of NullPointerException, log not outputting as desired

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm getting the following error:

```
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228): Process: com.dionsoft.dailymacrotracker, PID: 2228
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.dionsoft.dailymacrotracker/com.dionsoft.dailymacrotracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at com.dionsoft.dailymacrotracker.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:30)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
03-02 18:11:00.307: E/AndroidRuntime(2228):     ... 12 more
```

Here is the code for MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MainDS datasource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Map<String, Integer> todaysTotals = datasource.getTodaysTotals();
    }

}
```

Here is the code for MainDS:

```
public class MainDS {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private SQLiteHelper dbHelper;

    public MainDS(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getTodaysTotals () {
        String sql = "select sum(" + SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CALORIES + "), " +
                "sum(" + SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PROTEIN + "), " +
                "sum(" + SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CARBS + "), " +
                "sum(" + SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FAT + ") " +
                "from " + SQLiteHelper.TABLE_RECORDS + " " +
                "where date(" + SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE + ", 'unixepoch') = date('now')";
        Log.d("getTodaysTotals", sql);
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);

        Map<String, Integer> totals = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        if (cursor != null) { 
            totals.put("todays_calories", cursor.getInt(0));
            totals.put("todays_protein", cursor.getInt(1));
            totals.put("todays_carbs", cursor.getInt(2));
            totals.put("todays_fat", cursor.getInt(3));
        }

        cursor.close();

        return totals;
    }

}
```

I have no idea how to fix this because it is not telling me what I need to fix.

Also, it is not logging the sql from the Log.d function within MainDS at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `at com.dionsoft.dailymacrotracker.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:30)`, `Map<String, Integer> todaysTotals = datasource.getTodaysTotals();` -- `datasource` is null

Comment: sometimes happens :) Accept any of the three answer to avoid to keep this question open...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed

```
datasource = new MainDS(this);
```

in onCreate

```
private MainDS datasource;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

to

```
private MainDS datasource;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    datasource = new MainDS(this); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
datasource.getTodaysTotals();
```

you try using datasource but you never initialized it! ==> NPE